# В чем разница между переменными типа bool и Boolean?

Tags: c#

В чем разница между типами `bool` и `Boolean` в C#?

Comment: `bool` - псевдоним для `System.Boolean`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c-sharp. Первая ссылка в Гугле по запросу `C# bool vs boolean`. Причем даже заавтокомплитилось. Учитесь уже пользоваться гуглом.

Comment: Не понимаю такого минусования. Я лично вижу свою цель как пользователя русского SO  - чтобы гугл выдавал как раз эту страницу. Обратите внимание - в правилах SO рекоммендуют плюсовать одновременно и вопрос и ответ. В англоязычном SO у вопросов и ответов как правило сходный рейтинг.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Boolean` - это `value` -тип (структура), определенный в `CTS` (Common Type System) в пространтсве имен `System`.

`bool` - это тип (и ключевое слово), определенный в C#, который соответствует типу CTS `System.Boolean`. Преимущество использования собственного типа C# `bool` состоит в том, что вам не надо указывать ни квалифицированное имя, как в случае с `System.Boolean`, ни директиву `using System`, чтобы использовать этот тип.

Например, если вы напишите

```
Boolean b;
```

и не включите директиву

```
using System;
```

то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, тогда как можно писать

```
bool b;
```

не заботясь о пространствах имен, так как это ключевое слово языка C#.

Кстати сказать, для русскоговорящих имеется проблема: как правильно перевести словосочетание CTS. То ли это  Система Общих Типов, то ли это Общая Система Типов.

Я задавал такой [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600075/meaning-of-words-cts) на SO. Там мой вопрос заминусован, так как для англо-язычных стран он, наверное, очевиден, однако не очевиден для русско-говорящих. И особенно важен для переводчиков технической литературы по программированию. Поэтому, у кого есть желание, и кто считает этот вопрос важным, то можете там "плюсонуть" мой вопрос.:)

Итак, как выяснилось, правильно переводить словосочетание CTS как **Общая Система Типов**.

Comment: ну два минуса - не так уж и заминусовали, просто вопрос, как мне кажется, слишком общий, поэтому и минусы, там обычно спрашивали про _int_ vs _System.Int32_

Comment: заплюсовал вас на SO English :). и еще в MSDN написал - посмотрим, исправят они или нет. Пишите туда, они иногда исправляют: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy Спасибо. Я не исключаю, что может быть и ответ на мой вопрос не является корректным.:) Так что чем больше источников информации о значении этой аббревиатуры, тем лучше.:)

Answer (score 3):

Ни в чем. bool - это алиас (псевдоним) для Boolean